# How to get all installed font path/filename on Windows?

Tags: python, windows, fonts

How to get all installed font path in python on Windows?

I would like to use GDI or DirectWrite.

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/add-a-font-b7c5f17c-4426-4b53-967f-455339c564c1#:~:text=All%20fonts%20are%20stored%20in,file%2C%20and%20then%20click%20Preview, https://www.isunshare.com/windows-10/2-ways-to-view-installed-fonts-in-windows-10.html.

Comment: Bot link are not what i am looking for.

Comment: Please elaborate your question a bit. Why do you need that particular thing? Why isn't the registry way ok? Why would you even need the path(s), instead of working with the *API*s? This could be an *XY Problem*.

Comment: I did ask a method with pywin32 or any other way with python.

I did not ask a way with windows gui.

Comment: This gives a whole new perspective. Why didn't you just hardcode them (until finding a better way)? Do you have any code?

Comment: I edited my question with possible logic with directwrite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solution with DirectWrite

Dependencies:

- [comtypes](https://pypi.org/project/comtypes/)

The solution contains 2 methods since the one for Windows 10 is much faster then the one for Windows 7 or more.

```py
import comtypes
import sys
import time
from ctypes import byref, create_unicode_buffer, POINTER, windll, wintypes
from enum import IntEnum
from typing import Set


DWriteCreateFactory = windll.dwrite.DWriteCreateFactory
DWriteCreateFactory.restype = comtypes.HRESULT
DWriteCreateFactory.argtypes = [wintypes.UINT, comtypes.GUID, POINTER(POINTER(comtypes.IUnknown))]


class DWRITE_FACTORY_TYPE(IntEnum):
    # https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/dwrite/ne-dwrite-dwrite_factory_type
    DWRITE_FACTORY_TYPE_SHARED = 0
    DWRITE_FACTORY_TYPE_ISOLATED = 1


class IDWriteFontFileLoader(comtypes.IUnknown):
    # https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/dwrite/nn-dwrite-idwritefontfileloader
    _iid_ = comtypes.GUID("{727cad4e-d6af-4c9e-8a08-d695b11caa49}")
    _methods_ = [
        comtypes.STDMETHOD(None, "CreateStreamFromKey"), # Need to be implemented
    ]


class IDWriteLocalFontFileLoader(IDWriteFontFileLoader):
    # https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/directwrite/idwritelocalfontfileloader
    _iid_ = comtypes.GUID("{b2d9f3ec-c9fe-4a11-a2ec-d86208f7c0a2}")
    _methods_ = [
        comtypes.STDMETHOD(None, "GetFilePathLengthFromKey", [wintypes.LPCVOID, wintypes.UINT, POINTER(wintypes.UINT)]),
        comtypes.STDMETHOD(None, "GetFilePathFromKey",  [wintypes.LPCVOID, wintypes.UINT, POINTER(wintypes.WCHAR), wintypes.UINT]),
        comtypes.STDMETHOD(None, "GetLastWriteTimeFromKey"), # Need to be implemented
    ]


class IDWriteFontFile(comtypes.IUnknown):
    # https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/dwrite/nn-dwrite-idwritefontfile
    _iid_ = comtypes.GUID("{739d886a-cef5-47dc-8769-1a8b41bebbb0}")
    _methods_ = [
        comtypes.STDMETHOD(comtypes.HRESULT, "GetReferenceKey", [POINTER(wintypes.LPCVOID), POINTER(wintypes.UINT)]),
        comtypes.STDMETHOD(comtypes.HRESULT, "GetLoader", [POINTER(POINTER(IDWriteFontFileLoader))]),
        comtypes.STDMETHOD(None, "Analyze"), # Need to be implemented
    ]


class IDWriteFontFaceReference(comtypes.IUnknown):
    # https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/dwrite_3/nn-dwrite_3-idwritefontfacereference
    _iid_ = comtypes.GUID("{5E7FA7CA-DDE3-424C-89F0-9FCD6FED58CD}")
    _methods_ = [
        comtypes.STDMETHOD(None, "CreateFontFace"), # Need to be implemented
        comtypes.STDMETHOD(None, "CreateFontFaceWithSimulations"), # Need to be implemented
        comtypes.STDMETHOD(None, "Equals"), # Need to be implemented
        comtypes.STDMETHOD(None, "GetFontFaceIndex"), # Need to be implemented
        comtypes.STDMETHOD(None, "GetSimulations"), # Need to be implemented
        comtypes.STDMETHOD(comtypes.HRESULT, "GetFontFile", [POINTER(POINTER(IDWriteFontFile))]),
        comtypes.STDMETHOD(None, "GetLocalFileSize"), # Need to be implemented
        comtypes.STDMETHOD(None, "GetFileSize"), # Need to be implemented
        comtypes.STDMETHOD(None, "GetFileTime"), # Need to be implemented
        comtypes.STDMETHOD(None, "GetLocality"), # Need to be implemented
        comtypes.STDMETHOD(None, "EnqueueFontDownloadRequest"), # Need to be implemented
        comtypes.STDMETHOD(None, "EnqueueCharacterDownloadRequest"), # Need to be implemented
        comtypes.STDMETHOD(None, "EnqueueGlyphDownloadRequest"), # Need to be implemented
        comtypes.STDMETHOD(None, "EnqueueFileFragmentDownloadRequest"), # Need to be implemented
    ]


class IDWriteFontSet(comtypes.IUnknown):
    # https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/dwrite_3/nn-dwrite_3-idwritefontset
    _iid_ = comtypes.GUID("{53585141-D9F8-4095-8321-D73CF6BD116B}")
    _methods_ = [
        comtypes.STDMETHOD(wintypes.UINT, "GetFontCount"),
        comtypes.STDMETHOD(comtypes.HRESULT, "GetFontFaceReference", [wintypes.UINT, POINTER(POINTER(IDWriteFontFaceReference))]),
        comtypes.STDMETHOD(None, "FindFontFaceReference"), # Need to be implemented
        comtypes.STDMETHOD(None, "FindFontFace"), # Need to be implemented
        comtypes.STDMETHOD(None, "GetPropertyValues"), # Need to be implemented
        comtypes.STDMETHOD(None, "GetPropertyValues"), # Need to be implemented
        comtypes.STDMETHOD(None, "GetPropertyValues"), # Need to be implemented
        comtypes.STDMETHOD(None, "GetPropertyOccurrenceCount"), # Need to be implemented
        comtypes.STDMETHOD(None, "GetMatchingFonts"), # Need to be implemented
        comtypes.STDMETHOD(None, "GetMatchingFonts"), # Need to be implemented
    ]


class IDWriteFontFace(comtypes.IUnknown):
    # https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/dwrite/nn-dwrite-idwritefontface
    _iid_ = comtypes.GUID("{5f49804d-7024-4d43-bfa9-d25984f53849}")
    _methods_ = [
        comtypes.STDMETHOD(None, "GetType"), # Need to be implemented
        comtypes.STDMETHOD(comtypes.HRESULT, "GetFiles", [POINTER(wintypes.UINT), POINTER(POINTER(IDWriteFontFile))]),
        comtypes.STDMETHOD(None, "GetIndex"), # Need to be implemented
        comtypes.STDMETHOD(None, "GetSimulations"), # Need to be implemented
        comtypes.STDMETHOD(None, "IsSymbolFont"), # Need to be implemented
        comtypes.STDMETHOD(None, "GetMetrics"), # Need to be implemented
        comtypes.STDMETHOD(None, "GetGlyphCount"), # Need to be implemented
        comtypes.STDMETHOD(None, "GetDesignGlyphMetrics"), # Need to be implemented
        comtypes.STDMETHOD(None, "GetGlyphIndices"), # Need to be implemented
        comtypes.STDMETHOD(None, "TryGetFontTable"), # Need to be implemented
        comtypes.STDMETHOD(None, "ReleaseFontTable"), # Need to be implemented
        comtypes.STDMETHOD(None, "GetGlyphRunOutline"), # Need to be implemented
        comtypes.STDMETHOD(None, "GetRecommendedRenderingMode"), # Need to be implemented
        comtypes.STDMETHOD(None, "GetGdiCompatibleMetrics"), # Need to be implemented
        comtypes.STDMETHOD(None, "GetGdiCompatibleGlyphMetrics"), # Need to be implemented
    ]


class IDWriteFont(comtypes.IUnknown):
    # https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/dwrite/nn-dwrite-idwritefont
    _iid_ = comtypes.GUID("{acd16696-8c14-4f5d-877e-fe3fc1d32737}")
    _methods_ = [
        comtypes.STDMETHOD(None, "GetFontFamily"), # Need to be implemented
        comtypes.STDMETHOD(None, "GetWeight"), # Need to be implemented
        comtypes.STDMETHOD(None, "GetStretch"), # Need to be implemented
        comtypes.STDMETHOD(None, "GetStyle"), # Need to be implemented
        comtypes.STDMETHOD(None, "IsSymbolFont"), # Need to be implemented
        comtypes.STDMETHOD(None, "GetFaceNames"), # Need to be implemented
        comtypes.STDMETHOD(None, "GetInformationalStrings"), # Need to be implemented
        comtypes.STDMETHOD(None, "GetSimulations"), # Need to be implemented
        comtypes.STDMETHOD(None, "GetMetrics"), # Need to be implemented
        comtypes.STDMETHOD(None, "HasCharacter"), # Need to be implemented
        comtypes.STDMETHOD(comtypes.HRESULT, "CreateFontFace", [POINTER(POINTER(IDWriteFontFace))]),
    ]


class IDWriteFontList(comtypes.IUnknown):
    # https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/dwrite/nn-dwrite-idwritefontlist
    _iid_ = comtypes.GUID("{1a0d8438-1d97-4ec1-aef9-a2fb86ed6acb}")
    _methods_ = [
        comtypes.STDMETHOD(None, "GetFontCollection"), # Need to be implemented
        comtypes.STDMETHOD(wintypes.UINT, "GetFontCount"),
        comtypes.STDMETHOD(comtypes.HRESULT, "GetFont", [wintypes.UINT, POINTER(POINTER(IDWriteFont))]),
    ]


class IDWriteFontFamily(IDWriteFontList):
    # https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/dwrite/nn-dwrite-idwritefontfamily
    _iid_ = comtypes.GUID("{da20d8ef-812a-4c43-9802-62ec4abd7add}")
    _methods_ = [
        comtypes.STDMETHOD(None, "GetFamilyNames"), # Need to be implemented
        comtypes.STDMETHOD(None, "GetFirstMatchingFont"), # Need to be implemented
        comtypes.STDMETHOD(None, "GetMatchingFonts"), # Need to be implemented
    ]


class IDWriteFontCollection(comtypes.IUnknown):
    # https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/dwrite/nn-dwrite-idwritefontcollection
    _iid_ = comtypes.GUID("{a84cee02-3eea-4eee-a827-87c1a02a0fcc}")
    _methods_ = [
        comtypes.STDMETHOD(wintypes.UINT, "GetFontFamilyCount"),
        comtypes.STDMETHOD(comtypes.HRESULT, "GetFontFamily", [wintypes.UINT, POINTER(POINTER(IDWriteFontFamily))]),
        comtypes.STDMETHOD(None, "FindFamilyName"), # Need to be implemented
        comtypes.STDMETHOD(None, "GetFontFromFontFace"), # Need to be implemented
    ]


class IDWriteFactory(comtypes.IUnknown):
    # https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/dwrite/nn-dwrite-idwritefactory
    _iid_ = comtypes.GUID("{b859ee5a-d838-4b5b-a2e8-1adc7d93db48}")
    _methods_ = [
        comtypes.STDMETHOD(comtypes.HRESULT, "GetSystemFontCollection", [POINTER(POINTER(IDWriteFontCollection)), wintypes.BOOLEAN]),
        comtypes.STDMETHOD(None, "CreateCustomFontCollection"), # Need to be implemented
        comtypes.STDMETHOD(None, "RegisterFontCollectionLoader"), # Need to be implemented
        comtypes.STDMETHOD(None, "UnregisterFontCollectionLoader"), # Need to be implemented
        comtypes.STDMETHOD(None, "CreateFontFileReference"), # Need to be implemented
        comtypes.STDMETHOD(None, "CreateCustomFontFileReference"), # Need to be implemented
        comtypes.STDMETHOD(None, "CreateFontFace"), # Need to be implemented
        comtypes.STDMETHOD(None, "CreateRenderingParams"), # Need to be implemented
        comtypes.STDMETHOD(None, "CreateMonitorRenderingParams"), # Need to be implemented
        comtypes.STDMETHOD(None, "CreateCustomRenderingParams"), # Need to be implemented
        comtypes.STDMETHOD(None, "RegisterFontFileLoader"), # Need to be implemented
        comtypes.STDMETHOD(None, "UnregisterFontFileLoader"), # Need to be implemented
        comtypes.STDMETHOD(None, "CreateTextFormat"), # Need to be implemented
        comtypes.STDMETHOD(None, "CreateTypography"), # Need to be implemented
        comtypes.STDMETHOD(None, "GetGdiInterop"), # Need to be implemented
        comtypes.STDMETHOD(None, "CreateTextLayout"), # Need to be implemented
        comtypes.STDMETHOD(None, "CreateGdiCompatibleTextLayout"), # Need to be implemented
        comtypes.STDMETHOD(None, "CreateEllipsisTrimmingSign"), # Need to be implemented
        comtypes.STDMETHOD(None, "CreateTextAnalyzer"), # Need to be implemented
        comtypes.STDMETHOD(None, "CreateNumberSubstitution"), # Need to be implemented
        comtypes.STDMETHOD(None, "CreateGlyphRunAnalysis"), # Need to be implemented
    ]


class IDWriteFactory1(IDWriteFactory):
    # https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/dwrite_1/nn-dwrite_1-idwritefactory1
    _iid_ = comtypes.GUID("{30572f99-dac6-41db-a16e-0486307e606a}")
    _methods_ = [
        comtypes.STDMETHOD(None, "GetEudcFontCollection"), # Need to be implemented
        comtypes.STDMETHOD(None, "CreateCustomRenderingParams1"), # Need to be implemented
    ]


class IDWriteFactory2(IDWriteFactory1):
    # https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/dwrite_2/nn-dwrite_2-idwritefactory2
    _iid_ = comtypes.GUID("{0439fc60-ca44-4994-8dee-3a9af7b732ec}")
    _methods_ = [
        comtypes.STDMETHOD(None, "GetSystemFontFallback"), # Need to be implemented
        comtypes.STDMETHOD(None, "CreateFontFallbackBuilder"), # Need to be implemented
        comtypes.STDMETHOD(None, "TranslateColorGlyphRun"), # Need to be implemented
        comtypes.STDMETHOD(None, "CreateCustomRenderingParams2"), # Need to be implemented
        comtypes.STDMETHOD(None, "CreateGlyphRunAnalysis"), # Need to be implemented
    ]


class IDWriteFactory3(IDWriteFactory2):
    # https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/dwrite_3/nn-dwrite_3-idwritefactory3
    _iid_ = comtypes.GUID("{9A1B41C3-D3BB-466A-87FC-FE67556A3B65}")
    _methods_ = [
        comtypes.STDMETHOD(None, "CreateGlyphRunAnalysis"), # Need to be implemented
        comtypes.STDMETHOD(None, "CreateCustomRenderingParams3"), # Need to be implemented
        comtypes.STDMETHOD(None, "CreateFontFaceReference"), # Need to be implemented
        comtypes.STDMETHOD(None, "CreateFontFaceReference"), # Need to be implemented
        comtypes.STDMETHOD(comtypes.HRESULT, "GetSystemFontSet", [POINTER(POINTER(IDWriteFontSet))]),
        comtypes.STDMETHOD(None, "CreateFontSetBuilder"), # Need to be implemented
        comtypes.STDMETHOD(None, "CreateFontCollectionFromFontSet"), # Need to be implemented
        comtypes.STDMETHOD(None, "GetSystemFontCollection3"), # Need to be implemented
        comtypes.STDMETHOD(None, "GetFontDownloadQueue"), # Need to be implemented
    ]


def get_fonts_filepath_windows_10_or_more() -> Set[str]:
    """
    Return an list of all the font installed.
    """
    fonts_path = set()

    dwrite_factory = POINTER(IDWriteFactory3)()
    DWriteCreateFactory(DWRITE_FACTORY_TYPE.DWRITE_FACTORY_TYPE_ISOLATED, IDWriteFactory3._iid_, byref(dwrite_factory))

    font_set = POINTER(IDWriteFontSet)()
    dwrite_factory.GetSystemFontSet(byref(font_set))

    for i in range(font_set.GetFontCount()):
        font_face_reference = POINTER(IDWriteFontFaceReference)()
        font_set.GetFontFaceReference(i, byref(font_face_reference))

        font_file = POINTER(IDWriteFontFile)()
        font_face_reference.GetFontFile(byref(font_file))

        loader = POINTER(IDWriteFontFileLoader)()
        font_file.GetLoader(byref(loader))

        font_file_reference_key = wintypes.LPCVOID()
        font_file_reference_key_size = wintypes.UINT()
        font_file.GetReferenceKey(byref(font_file_reference_key), byref(font_file_reference_key_size))

        try:
            local_loader = loader.QueryInterface(IDWriteLocalFontFileLoader)
        except comtypes.COMError:
            continue

        path_len = wintypes.UINT()
        local_loader.GetFilePathLengthFromKey(font_file_reference_key, font_file_reference_key_size, byref(path_len))

        buffer = create_unicode_buffer(path_len.value + 1)
        local_loader.GetFilePathFromKey(font_file_reference_key, font_file_reference_key_size, buffer, len(buffer))

        fonts_path.add(buffer.value)

    return fonts_path


def get_fonts_filepath_windows_7_or_more() -> Set[str]:
    """
    Return an list of all the font installed.
    """
    fonts_path = set()

    dwrite_factory = POINTER(IDWriteFactory)()
    DWriteCreateFactory(DWRITE_FACTORY_TYPE.DWRITE_FACTORY_TYPE_ISOLATED, IDWriteFactory._iid_, byref(dwrite_factory))

    sys_collection = POINTER(IDWriteFontCollection)()
    dwrite_factory.GetSystemFontCollection(byref(sys_collection), False)

    for i in range(sys_collection.GetFontFamilyCount()):
        family = POINTER(IDWriteFontFamily)()
        sys_collection.GetFontFamily(i, byref(family))

        for j in range(family.GetFontCount()):
            font = POINTER(IDWriteFont)()
            family.GetFont(j, byref(font))

            font_face = POINTER(IDWriteFontFace)()
            font.CreateFontFace(byref(font_face))

            file_count = wintypes.UINT()
            font_face.GetFiles(byref(file_count), None)

            font_files = (POINTER(IDWriteFontFile)* file_count.value)()
            font_face.GetFiles(byref(file_count), font_files)

            for font_file in font_files:
                font_file_reference_key = wintypes.LPCVOID()
                font_file_reference_key_size = wintypes.UINT()
                font_file.GetReferenceKey(byref(font_file_reference_key), byref(font_file_reference_key_size))

                loader = POINTER(IDWriteFontFileLoader)()
                font_file.GetLoader(byref(loader))

                try:
                    local_loader = loader.QueryInterface(IDWriteLocalFontFileLoader)
                except comtypes.COMError:
                    continue

                path_len = wintypes.UINT()
                local_loader.GetFilePathLengthFromKey(font_file_reference_key, font_file_reference_key_size, byref(path_len))

                buffer = create_unicode_buffer(path_len.value + 1)
                local_loader.GetFilePathFromKey(font_file_reference_key, font_file_reference_key_size, buffer, len(buffer))

                fonts_path.add(buffer.value)

    return fonts_path


def is_windows_version_or_greater(windows_version, major: int, minor: int, service_pack_major: int) -> bool:
    """
    Parameters:
        windows_version: An object from sys.getwindowsversion.
        major (int): The minimum major OS version number.
        minor (int): The minimum minor OS version number.
        service_pack_major (int): The minimum major Service Pack version number.
    Returns:
        True if the specified version matches or if it is greater than the version of the current Windows OS. Otherwise, False.
    """

    if windows_version.major > major:
        return True
    elif windows_version.major == major and windows_version.minor > minor:
        return True
    else:
        return windows_version.major == major and windows_version.minor == minor and windows_version.service_pack_major >= service_pack_major


def is_windows_vista_sp2_or_greater(windows_version) -> bool:
    return is_windows_version_or_greater(windows_version, 6, 0, 2)


def is_windows_10_or_greater(windows_version) -> bool:
    return is_windows_version_or_greater(windows_version, 10, 0, 0)


def main():
    start = time.time()

    if sys.platform == "win32":
        windows_version = sys.getwindowsversion()

        if is_windows_10_or_greater(windows_version):
            fonts_path_dwrite = get_fonts_filepath_windows_10_or_more()
        elif is_windows_vista_sp2_or_greater(windows_version):
            fonts_path_dwrite = get_fonts_filepath_windows_7_or_more()
        else:
            raise Exception("This script only works on Windows 7 or more")
    else:
        raise Exception("This script only works on Windows.")

    print(fonts_path_dwrite)
    print(f"Time elapsed: {time.time() - start}")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    sys.exit(main())
```

### Solution with Windows registry key

Dependencies:

- [pywin32](https://pypi.org/project/pywin32/)

```py
import os
import sys
import time
import winreg
from win32com.shell import shell, shellcon


def get_win32_system_font():
    with winreg.OpenKey(winreg.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, "SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows NT\\CurrentVersion\\Fonts") as key:
        paths = []
        info = winreg.QueryInfoKey(key)
        fonts_root = shell.SHGetKnownFolderPath(shellcon.FOLDERID_Fonts)

        for index in range(info[1]):
            value = winreg.EnumValue(key, index)
            path = value[1] if os.path.isabs(value[1]) else os.path.join(fonts_root, value[1])
            paths.append(path)
        
        return paths

def get_win32_user_font():
    with winreg.OpenKey(winreg.HKEY_CURRENT_USER, "SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows NT\\CurrentVersion\\Fonts") as key:
        paths = []
        info = winreg.QueryInfoKey(key)
        for index in range(info[1]):
            value = winreg.EnumValue(key, index)
            paths.append(value[1])
        
        return paths


def main():
    start = time.time()
    system_font = get_win32_system_font()
    user_font = get_win32_user_font()
    print(time.time() - start)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    sys.exit(main())
```

### Solution with matplotlib

Dependencies:

- [matplotlib](https://pypi.org/project/matplotlib/)

```py
import sys
import time
from matplotlib import font_manager

def main():
    start = time.time()
    fonts_paths  = set(font_manager.findSystemFonts())
    print(time.time() - start)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    sys.exit(main())
```

### Solution with FindSystemFontsFilename

Dependencies:

- [FindSystemFontsFilename](https://pypi.org/project/FindSystemFontsFilename/)

```py
from find_system_fonts_filename import get_system_fonts_filename, FontConfigNotFound, OSNotSupported

try:
    fonts_filename = get_system_fonts_filename()
except (FontConfigNotFound, OSNotSupported):
    # Deal with the exception
    # OSNotSupported can only happen in Windows and macOS
    #   - Windows Vista SP2 and more are supported
    #   - macOS 10.6 and more are supported
    # FontConfigNotFound can only happen on Linux when Fontconfig could't be found.
    pass
```